# Imputing missing values with a specific mean and median of other variables in python

Tags: python, data-science

From a dataset where the column "Experience" has a lot of missing values, I'm asked to impute them with the mean of the experience of the other job in the dataset and with the median of the experience of the other one. Someone could help? thanks

Trying the get the mean of the experience of the data scientists

```
#Creating a dataFrame
Data_science = df[["Metier", "Experience"]].copy()
Data_science

Data_science.isnull().sum()
output : Metier        19
Experience    94
dtype: int64

moyenne_dataS = Data_science['Experience'].mean()
moyenne_dataS
```

output: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 moyenne_dataS = Data_science[str(int['Experience'])].mean()
>         2 moyenne_dataS
>
> TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Getting errors and don't know to get the specific mean of the experience of the data scientists and the median of the data engineers

Answer (score 0):

You can try to filter null values before calculating mean and median, example:

```
Data_science[~Data_science['Experience'].isnull()]['Experience'].mean()
Data_science[~Data_science['Experience'].isnull()]['Experience'].median()
```

Comment: Thanks ! It returns "nan". The null values are labeled with NaN. What I'm trying to do, is to find the mean of experience of only the data scientists and not the mean of all the column expercience

Comment: Then you can add filtering, for example: `Data_science[(~Data_science['Experience'].isnull()) & (Data_science['Metier'] == 'data_science')]['Experience'].mean()`